# Threshold values b in SVM implementations

Tags: svm, libsvm, numerical, svmlight, cvxopt

I was playing around with my own crude implementation for SVMs using cvxopt for solving the Quadratic programming problem inherent.I am a newbie to SVMs.

Because it is my own implementation the onus of figuring out the margin support vectors and the threshold b of the separating plane is on me. On a fair sized (approx 5K samples, 2 dimensional numeric input) data set, in a soft SVM formulation, I ran into the problem while trying to figure out the margin support vectors.

The margin support vectors are the nonzero alphas that are smaller than C. However if I blindly use cvxopt's feastol parameter to determine what alphas can be deemed C and what can be deemed smaller than C, I found that the threshold values b derived from each margin support vector differ considerably, sometimes strikingly. (Theoretically the thresholds b derived from any of the margin support vectors are supposed to be the same)

Sometimes adhoc thresholding works but sometimes it doesnt seem to be feasible -- Maybe there is a way of cleverly trying out different threshold values to get some 'least inconsistent' set of b's or some such.

(a) Is such a situation encountered in practice by real practitioners (or 'inside' implementations such as libsvm or svm-light etc) or does this sound like bugs or implementation issues in my specific case?

(b) If this is indeed a problem in practice how is it resolved: The SVM tutorial by Burges states that you just take an average of all the thresholds derived from the margin support vectors -- This is also what's done in the matlab code in Gunn's tech report (http://www.ecs.soton.ac.uk/~srg/publications/pdf/SVM.pdf ). Is that the simple way out and works well in practice, and is this whats done in libsvm or svm-light etc? Or is there some principled way to try out different threshold values to get the least inconsistent acceptable set of thresholds b ?

Comment: One question... Which problem are you solving? The primal,or dual?

Comment: The dual -- specifically 7.20 through 7.24 on http://www.mblondel.org/journal/2010/09/19/support-vector-machines-in-python/